# How to adjust the type of Nuxt Route Middleware with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to make a route middleware that would check the `request.meta.auth` field from request object and type it with TypeScript:

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((request) => {
  request.meta.auth // For this to have autocomplete of 'user' and 'guest'
});
```

How can I do that?

I tried

```
declare module "nuxt" {
  interface RouteLocationNormalized {
    meta: {
      auth: TAuthVariant;
    };
  }
}
```

But it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

```
declare module '#app' {
  interface PageMeta {
    auth: TAuthVariant;
  }
}
```

worked